# How to get all the students of a department in Mongoose MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongoose-schema

I am an amateur in MongoDB, trying to build an educational database.

I have two document models: 1) Department 2) Student

Each Student document has ref: Department with its _id.

So, If I have the Department _id, how can I find all the students it has?

```
const department = mongoose.schema({
  name: { type: String } 
})
const student = mongoose.schema({
  name: { type: String },
  department: { mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Department}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) like this:

Using this `$lookup` you are telling mongo "give me all documents from `student` collection where its `department` field is like `_id` field in `department` collection and create an array called `departmens` with these values.

```
yourDepartmentModel.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "student",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "department",
      "as": "departments"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JgINZDtg9If)

Comment: Great, although not to the point, but I got my solution from aggregation framework i didn't know about earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **the easiest way to find all the entries or elements in a single collection is the following**

```
let filter = {};
let result = await your User.find(filter);
Where: User is your Data Model and You can change it according to your database
```